# Does Facebook have some sort of API that I can make a client?

Tags: api, facebook, client

For example...I would like to make a "client".  First, people post to my client, and then to Facebook.

(I want to make a client so that I can store posts)

Comment: what do u mean by client here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has a number of APIs, including ones which will allow you to do the thing you describe.  The term "posts" is a little vague since that covers a number of things on Facebook, but as an example there is the [`Status.Set` API Call](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Status.set) you can be used to update a user's status.

A useful place to start would be the [Facebook Developer Wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 2):

You should try "Google" before posting a question. There's a portal for developing applications on Facebook called...

- **[Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/)**

By client API, I assume you wanted a "Desktop" client, if so you probably wanted the...

- **[Facebook Server API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API)**

...which you can use to add a post/comment, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If your are targeting a .NET environment (ASP.NET, Silverlight, WM, ...) you should take a look to this toolkit: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/